# Powershell - Adding computers to a security group in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can I add multiple computer accounts from within a text file into a security group in Active Directory? I put this snippet of code together but it only works with user accounts.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-Content C:\Servers.txt | Foreach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember "WSUS Auto Download and Notify for Install" $_}
```

Comment: The account name for a computer has a $ tacked on to the end of it.  Did you do that?  (The account name for a server named "server1" is "server1$".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you are looking for is Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership.

```
Get-Content c:\servers.txt | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMember -memberof 'WSUS Auto Download and Notify for Install'
```

If you need to add the "$" at the end of the computer name, your command could use a scriptblock parameter (an anoymous function that can modify pipeline input).

```
Get-Content c:\servers.txt | Add-ADPrincipalGroupMember -memberof 'WSUS Auto Download and Notify for Install' -identity {"$_$"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use -Identity $_.objectGUID

$_$ didn't work for me.

EDIT: Ah, sorry, that's because I use Get-ADComputer to pipe it, and not a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar task found [info on this link](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=4221) worked for me,

Run it in powershell as admin

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$List=Get-Content c:\computers.txt
$List | foreach {Add-ADGroupMember -id ADGroupName -MEMBERS (Get-ADComputer $_)
```